# When does BAM track if running from a tracking profile

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013, biztalk-bam

If using a tracking profile, built using the TPE - when does the message get tracked?

I had thought it would always track before maps are applied on receive ports and track after maps are applied on send ports, but this seems not to be the case.
I can't find documentation of this on MSDN.

I am using BizTalk 2013r1

Comment: The tracking apparently happens in the Pipelines, so it should be as you describe, However there was a bug at one point that if you used a Pass-Thru pipeline that tracking would not work.  Are you on Cumulative Update 3?   Can you describe in your question what the behavior/issues you are getting?

Comment: What tracking are you seeing?  Are you using any custom pipelines?  Are you using any pass thru pipelines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more investigation and testing I found the following:

- The tracking profile is always applied at the end of the pipeline
- Maps applied directly to ports, in the conventional way are applied:

  - at the end of a receive pipeline
  - at the beginning of a send pipeline
- Standard Receive: adapter --> disassemble etc-->track-->map-->msgbox
- Standard Send: msgbox --> map --> assemble etc-->track --> adapter

In my case the tracking was happening after a received message had been mapped but this was because the particular receive location was using a customer pipeline component to execute the map, rather than relying on the "standard" method of assigning a map to use in the bindings.

Hope this helps somebody with the same problem in future